# Player didnt take damage from the Spikes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a platformer game, I created the UI for the Health and then I created the Player health.But when I created the Sprike script, it didnt work.Like,when I interect with the spike(with Box colider, is trigger) it resets the level.

I also created a `void Dead`, resets the level if `curHealth <= 0`,but I dont know why it restarts my lvl if i have 2 lives left(the player have 3 lives public `int maxHealth = 3;`)

The scripst are :

Spikes script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Spikes : MonoBehaviour

{

    private Player player;

    void Start(){

        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){

        if(col.CompareTag("Player")) {

            player.Damage(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Player script:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject blood;

    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private int extraJumps;
    public int extraJumpsValue;

    private bool facingRight =  true;

    public int curHealth;
    public int maxHealth = 3;

    void Start(){

        curHealth = maxHealth;

        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue; 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0){
            Flip();
        } else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0){
            Flip();
        }
    }

    void Update(){

        if(isGrounded == true){
            extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps > 0){
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            extraJumps--;
        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true){
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }

        if(curHealth > maxHealth){
            curHealth = maxHealth;
        }

        if(curHealth <= 0){
            Die ();
        }


       }
    void Flip(){

        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }

    void Die(){

        //Restart
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    void OnCollisonEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Spikes")){

            Instantiate ( blood, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void Damage(int dmg) {

        curHealth -= dmg;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see something.If i have void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) and i have player.Damage(1), it will do 1 damage for all the box collider on the Player. Someone can help me with this?How can i resolve it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check if you are touching a spike in the player's code and deal the damage there as opposed to checking if a spike is touching the player?

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks the tag of the gameObject/collider. If you have 3 colliders you will call Player.Damage() for every single one.
If you want to stick to your design, you will need to split them up to child objects and give them different tags like "PlayerParent" and "PlayerChild" or something like this.

You also could use the same tag for every child of the parent player object, but use the children on different layers than the parent. Check out how to ignore layers: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html

Just try to exclude the other non-important colliders from being detected in the OnTriggerEnter2D function. Maybe you could switch to OnCollisionEnter2D and don't let the player "fall into it"?
Hope this answers your question.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

OK On rigid body there is property Called Collision Detection change it to discrete (if it is on continuous) and try again